# Setting delays on $watch in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Here is my situation, I am using the select2 library so I can have a control where users can quickly add items to an input box. These items are bound to an array called `$scope.selectedServices.values`. So when an item gets added, it is added to that array and likewise if an item is removed then it gets removed from that array.

My problem is, I want to set up a `$watch` so I can update the database every time the list changes:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedServices.values', function() {
    // Call web service here with $http post
});
```

But if there's multiple rapid changes (say a couple of changes in the space of half a second), I don't want to fire off multiple `$http` calls.

Is it possible for me to set up a delay, such that it might only fire after 0.5 seconds? That way if there are rapid changes it will all be contained in the one web service call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can be writing a queue service. The outline could be something like this:

```
function queueService($timeout, $http) {
    this.queue   = [];
    this.running = false;

    this.enQueue = function(uri) {
        queue.push(uri);
        if (!this.running) {
            $timeout(this.handle, 500);
            this.running = true;
        }
    }

    this.handle = function() {
        // Make your single call here instead of multiple calls
        for (var i in this.queue) {
            $http.get(i); 
        }

        this.queue   = [];
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

Note that this is more like pseudo code and might not actually work as shown.

**Edit:**
I just realised that you would like to use this function from within a $watch. You might have simplified your example for the sake of the question, yet still I would like to point out that $watch might fire more often than expected. Using some logic to check if your value has actually changed is advised!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect Use Case for [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js/):

Just add the library as described in the documentation, then use it like:

```
angular.module('somemodule', ['rx'])
    .controller('someCtrl', function($scope, rx) {

        $scope
            .$toObservable('selectedServices.values')
            .throttle(500)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(function(val){
                 // To something like:
                 // $scope.results = val;
            });
```

Comment: So I wouldn't even need a `$watch` with this approach?

Comment: No, $toObservable is a rx replacement for $watch

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObservableBase' of undefined`. I have added a script reference to rx.angular.min.js and followed your code example above. Do I need to do something else? Do I need to use the var `rx`?

Comment: Did you initialize $scope.selectedServices.values before observing it?

Comment: Turned out I hadn't included the js file for RX (I'd only included the wrapper).